# Can we use bucketing in hive table backed by avro schema

Tags: hive, avro, bigdata

I am trying to  create one hive table backed by avro schema. Below is the DDL for that

```
CREATE TABLE avro_table
ROW FORMAT 
  SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'    
CLUSTERED BY (col_name) INTO N BUCKETS    
STORED AS 
  INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat' 
  OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'  
TBLPROPERTIES ( 'avro.schema.url' = 'hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/avroschema/test_schema.avsc')
```

But it is throwing below mentioned error

FAILED: ParseException line 3:3 missing EOF at 'clustered' near ''org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe''

I am not sure wheather we can use bucketing in Hive backed by AVRO or not

hive version--1.2

Can any one help me or provide any idea to achieve this .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is in the wrong order, and missing stuff.  `ROW FORMAT` is defined after `CLUSTERED BY`, and `CLUSTERED BY` requires a column name which presumably needs to be defined as part of the `CREATE TABLE` command.

I assume the `N` in `N BUCKETS` is really replaced with your actual number of buckets, but if not, that's another error.

I have formatted the query in your question so that I could read it, an[d comparing to syntax here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Create/Drop/TruncateTable) it was easier to spot what the parser didn't like.

Comment: CREATE TABLE s.TEST_OD_V(
  UniqueId int,
  dtCd string,
  SysSK int,
  Ind string)
PARTITIONED BY (vcd STRING)
CLUSTERED BY (UniqueId) INTO 500 BUCKETS
STORED AS AVRO;

if we create table using above HQL ....what is the location of the schema file...how to edit the schema file if I have to change the schema